# Get text from active accordian tab and change on click in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an accordian with 5 tabs
I am trying to display the text from the active page. 
When the page is visited the default active does display with the code I have 
but on click it does not trigger change.

```
    <script>
    $('h2 a.active').change(setDisplayText).on('click', function(e) {
    $('.sub_heading').html($(this).text());
    e.preventDefault();
    }); 
    </script>
```

h2 is in a OL LI span

Comment: can you create a fiddler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Solution:**
I've gotten the `.h2` to display the active header (used the console to inject js into your page). What you need to do is to define the `onSlideAnimComplete` option with a function.
Replacing the following line:

```
$('#three').liteAccordion({ theme : 'dark', rounded : true, enumerateSlides : false, firstSlide : 5, linkable : true, easing: 'easeInOutQuart' });
```

with: (I tidied up the spacing a bit)

```
$('#three').liteAccordion({
        theme : 'dark',
        rounded : true,
        enumerateSlides : false,
        firstSlide : 5,
        linkable : true,
        easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
        onSlideAnimComplete: function() {
                //Changes .h2 upon animation complete 
                $('.h2').html($('h2.selected span').html());
            }
    });
```

and then removing the lines:

```
<script>
        $('h2 a.active').change(setDisplayText).on('click', function(e) {
        $('.sub_heading').html($(this).text());
        e.preventDefault();
        });
        </script>
```

should get the functionality you're looking for (removing the last part is just to remove redundancy and the number of errors that show up in the console.)

You'll notice that `.h2` doesn't change immediately. I tried to first change the text using the `onTriggerSlide` option, but `h2.selected` doesn't transfer over to the new header until the animation has completed, so it displays the previous `h2.active`'s text. If you want to animate `.h2` to tailor it's transition, you could `fadeOut` (or whatever animation you want) on `onTriggerSlide` and then animate back in `onAnimSlideComplete`. [This page](http://nicolahibbert.com/demo/liteAccordion/) breaks down all the options/methods you have with liteAccordion.
Let me know if this works for you and if you need any more help :)

---

**Original Post:**
Since I don't have the larger context, I won't write any much code for you, but I'm pretty sure what you're looking for can be done by defining whatever you want to happen on click when you initialize the accordion by specifying either the activate or beforeActivate options. Check out http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate and I believe you should find your answer.

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, so you'll have to figure out whether to use ui.newHeader, ui.oldHeader, ui.newPanel, or ui.oldPanel and then what you want to do with them, but here is something to get you started:

```
$('.acc').accordion({
        activate: function(e,ui) {
                console.log(ui.newTab.html());
            });
    });
```

Comment: Sorry I should have included the example page. I have the accordian tabs named "example" and when the page intially loads the "yellow/gold" div would get the default value for the tab open. Then when the users changes the tab in the accordian the text in the gold/yellow box would follow suit and update. I have the initial value right but it does not change on update. http://turningpointrenovations.com/contact/default.html#slide-five

Comment: Thanks much, I appreciate this greatly, works just like I intended. Hats off !1